# Is there any word on what will happen to the Candidates Tournament 2020 if one of the players tests positive for COVID-19 (coronavirus)?

Tags: tournament, world-championship, candidates

With FIDE moving forward with the [Candidates Tournament 2020](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candidates_Tournament_2020), in my opinion against better judgment, they have announced what [medical screenings will be done](https://www.chess.com/news/view/coronavirus-testing-at-fide-candidates-chess-tournament), but have they announced what would happen should one of the players test positive for COVID-19 during the tournament?

There were over 400 people at the opening ceremony yesterday, and I think it would be a public relations nightmare if one of the players contracts it.

Comment: Doesn't answer your question but https://lichess.org/blog/XnAEbRAAAB8A6Q_X/candidates-2020---fide-declares-safety-is-our-priority might be of interest. As usual FIDE is making FIFA look like a model of transparency, integrity and good governance.

Comment: @IanBush I have read most of that on different sites, but that was an excellent compilation of a lot of information. Thank you. My guess is that they are just winging it with no real plan, and hoping it does not happen.

Comment: It was revealed on chess24 stream (yesterday or day before yesterday, I can't remember) that the tournament will be interrupted, current standings will be saved, and once the situation with the virus gets handled, it will resume were it left off.

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, in fact, the tournament has been put on a pause with the current standings, because they are not able to continue: https://www.chess.com/news/view/2020-fide-candidates-tournament-postponed